# How to map a Perforce depot's folder to an arbitrary local folder?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have the following structure on the Perforce server:

```
MyDepot
  + MyProject
    + MySubProject
      + trunk
        + ... trunk folders/files ...
```

I have my Eclipse workspace for `MySubProject` in:

```
C:\Users\<my username>\Documents\eclipse.wkspcs\MySubProject
```

If I get the latest revision with a Perforce workspace of:

```
C:\Users\<my username>\Documents\eclipse.wkspcs\MySubProject
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\<my username>\Documents\eclipse.wkspcs\MySubProject\
  + MyDepot
    + MyProject
      + MySubProject
        + trunk
          + ... trunk folders/files ...
```

I'd prefer:

```
C:\Users\<my username>\Documents\eclipse.wkspcs\MySubProject\
  + ... trunk folders/files ...
```

Can I achieve this and if, how?

I found the P4V manual page [Defining a Workspace View](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Defining_a_client_view.html) but it doesn't seem to cover what I want. (There's a garbled sentence under point 2. but this isn't essential in this respect, is it?)

Comment: I see the garbled text in my browser, too. I'll try to track that down. Meanwhile, I'm glad that the suggested solution works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing a garbled sentence under point 2, so try this via the command line:

```
p4 client
```

Change the root line to:

```
Root: C:\Users\<my username>\Documents\eclipse.wkspcs\MySubProject\
```

Change the View to:

```
View:
    //MyDepot/MyProject/MySubProject/trunk/... //<myclient>/...
```

(Note: mapping needs to be indented and on the line before "View:")

Comment: „_is displayed._“ immediately after a full stop is not a garbled sentence for you? Admitted, I'm not a native English speaker but this end doesn't make any sense to me in the context of the previous sentence. Can I perform the steps you describe inside the P4V client as well?

Comment: Right, not garbled for me. Probably a browser difference.

Comment: You can do the same thing from within P4V. Go to Connection-->Edit Current Workspace.  If you don't see the mappings as text, click on the icon at the far right of the dialog to view mappings as text. Change it to the above and save.

Comment: A browser difference? I viewed it with 4 different browsers (FF, IE, Chrome, Pale Moon). The end of the line „_2. In the **Workspaces** tab, context-click the workspace and select **Edit Workspace**.is displayed._“ doesn't make sense in any of them. However, I managed to achieve what I was looking for. Thanks!